# How do I query whether a row has N rows in another table that foreign key it?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the general setup.

I have the tables `Cards`, `Attributes`, and a join table between them. (Let's call it `Tags`. It contains a `CardID` and an `AttributeID`.) The `Attributes` table is mostly just descriptions such as `HasPower`, `IsPoisonous`, `ImmuneToWater`, etc.

How would I go about querying for all cards that are both `IsPoisonous` and `IsElectric`? Let's assume I have the IDs for those already (13 and 45), so technically, the `Attributes` table does not need to be part of this SQL. I concocted something like this, but I'm not even sure if it is optimal.

```
SELECT *, (COUNT * FROM Tags t WHERE t.CardID = c.CardID AND t.AttributeID IN (13, 45)) AS TagCount
FROM Cards c
WHERE TagCount = 2
```

I hope my question makes sense. Basically, imagine you are looking at a web UI; you are sifting through a pool of ~5000 cards and want to filter down your results. So, you start checking boxes: "Poisonous", "Electric", "Immune to Water", etc. The results then filter down based on those attributes.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Cards
WHERE (Cards.Id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CardID
    FROM Tags
    WHERE AttributeID IN (13, 45)
    GROUP BY CardID
    HAVING (COUNT(AttributeID) >= 2)
))
```

Inner query fetches the CardIDs that have at least two of the attributes you'd specified, then uses that result as a filter to fetch the actual card data in the outer query.

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward. I understand what it is doing. Do you think this would have performance issues as it scaled upward? I'm not too worried because the pool of cards I'm working with is not growing really, but I'm just concerned about expanding it to other/bigger card pools.

Comment: with appropriate indexing, this should scale fairly well, as long as you're not passing in (say) 500+ attributes to filter on.

Comment: Oh definitely. I would imagine that in an extreme case, a user might pass in... 12 attributes? While we're on this topic, what non-PK columns would you recommend enabling indexing on?

Comment: the rule of thumb of indexing is any field that's used in a condition: where clause, in clause, group by, etc...

Comment: this query has roughly `O(n+m)` time behavior, where `n` is total number of tags in the table and `m` number of selected cards.  It can get a little better by replacing the nested query with a JOIN, because the query optimizer can better detect a few extreme cases, but I doubt it would alter the general time curve.

Comment: @Javier But how would you do it with a join? Wouldn't that fundamentally alter the results?

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: roughly like `SELECT Cards.* FROM Cards JOIN Tags ON (Cards.ID=CardID) WHERE ... GROUP BY CardID HAVING ...` where each `...` is unchanged from the respective part in @Marc B's answer

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use multiple JOINs, I recommend you redesign your DB so that the attributes are simply columns in the Cards table.

Comment: So, you suggest just making one insanely wide table that has mostly NULL columns?

Comment: I'd say about 2/3 are bit columns, and 1/3 are numerical attributes. (I was going to add an `Amount` column to `Tags`.)

Comment: i mean, what is the actual number of attributes? a few hundred might not be so bad if they don't exceed mysql's limits. and it would perform well.

Comment: Oh, currently, I have about 44 attributes. I don't know how much more it will grow, but it is growing. :P